# Vim: Can not diff more than 4 buffers when trying to do three way merging in git

Tags: git, vim

I am trying to do three way merging with git and vim using the following tutorial: http://www.toofishes.net/blog/three-way-merging-git-using-vim/ but my Vim always gives me:

```
Can not diff more than 4 buffers
```

And it starts in weird state with five windows (the first one is empty). I tried to start it with -U NONE option to disable all my settings, but it is always the same. I do want the setup like from the picture (merged file at the bottom, three panes above).

```
git config --global mergetool.vimdiff3.cmd 'vim -f -d -c "wincmd J" "$MERGED" "$LOCAL" "$BASE" "$REMOTE"'
git config --global merge.tool vimdiff3
... making a conflict with git ...
git mergetool
... vim is starting ...
Vim shows: Can not diff more than 4 buffers
... hitting ENTER hides the error and I see scrambled windows ...
```

Where is the snag please?

Comment: What command *exactly* did you use to run your three way diff? Could this be a quote problem?

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that error, but I can note that that referenced tutorial is somewhat obsolete. Since git version 1.7.4 mergetool has been invoking (g)vimdiff in 3-way merge mode by default (due to work by that tutorial's author).

Comment: Ok thanks for the update. Also updating the question with the exact command now.